# Woocommerce product attributes not queried with get_terms()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

When I try to query my custom product attributes using

```
get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => array('pa_kolor'),
    'hide_empty' => false
));
```

It's working just fine. However, when I add any additional taxonomies, for example:

```
get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => array('category', 'pa_kolor', 'product_cat'),
    'hide_empty' => false
));
```

It only returns terms from `category` and `product_cat` taxonomies - ignoring the `pa_kolor`. 
I don't have any idea what may be causing this behaviour.

Comment: I guess you must have done something wrong as i tested the same code and it is working fine.. what is **pa_kolor**? Is that taxonomy of any other post type.. I have already tested in my installation and it already worked

Comment: **pa_kolor** is a product attribute added with woocommerce (in Products > Attributes). I am using a filter to alter the wp_query, but not the tax_query